# What is the purpose of "?"

Tags: c#, mobile

Im trying to understand mobile programming and then I came across this code for a method which is supposed to translate a character to a number. The code is working but my question is what is the purpose of the "?" after the int.

```
static int? Translate(char c)
        {
            if ("ABC".Contains(c))
                return 2;
            else if ("DEF".Contains(c))
                return 3;
            else if ("GHI".Contains(c))
                return 4;
            else if ("JKL".Contains(c))
                return 5;
            else if ("MNO".Contains(c))
                return 6;
            else if ("PQRS".Contains(c))
                return 7;
            else if ("TUV".Contains(c))
                return 8;
            else if ("WXYZ".Contains(c))
                return 9;

            return null;

        }
```

Comment: it indicates it is nullable ( so function can return null on error condition )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` is syntax sugar for the `Nullable<>` class -- in your case `int?` is actually `Nullable<Int32>`.

The purpose of this class is to allow value types to represent `null` values, since they normally can't (they're "stack" objects in C++ terms). It involves boxing however so use them only when needed, there is a performance cost associated with it.

Also note that setting that to `null` (through `return` in your case, or just a normal assignment) doesn't actually set the reference to `null`. This is more compiler magic that actually sets it to `new int?()`, an instance with the `HasValue` property set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can express that a value type is nullable in two ways:

1. nullable ,nullable , etc
2. int? double?

The question mark is only a shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

`int?` is just shorthand for `nullable<int>`. A nullable datatype is one that can represent either it's type (`int` is this case) or `null`. 32-bit integers represent any number is the following range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647; but nullable integers (`int?`) can be anything in that range, *or* `null`.